# Как получить доступ к методу другого класса в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть тест tests.tests_list

```
def test_exp(app):
    app.search360.exp()
```

Есть метод в классе MainClass в fixture.main

```
class MainClass:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
    def myfun(self):
        print("some text")
```

Есть метод в классе ExpClass в fixture.exp

```
class ExpClass:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
    def fun(self):
        ???
```

Есть еще класс Application в fixture.application:

```
from fixture.exp import ExpClass
from fixture.main import MainClass

class Application:
   def __init__(self):
   self.exp = ExpClass(self)
   self.main = MainClass(self)
```

Вопрос: как мне вызвать функцию из main в exp (где ???)?
Заранее благодарствую)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то в классе ExpClass метод должен выглядеть так:

```
def fun(self):
    self.app.main.myfun()
```

Comment: не получается =( когда пишу 
self.app. то он дает доступ только к методам внутри application

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "он даёт доступ только к методам application" ? У вас мой код с ошибкой падает? Если да, то приведите текст ошибки.

Comment: да, пардон) ваш вариант работает